# Unable to add favicon to my jsp

Tags: favicon

I am unable to add a favicon to my jsp page. Adding the favicon as a link to a specific path did not work for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here you can see my WebContent folder with what I tried, as well as the path to the icon I used.

[image: My Web-Content folder]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should put the favicon inside the Web-Content folder directly (not in the image folder) if you want the best compatibility with most browsers.

The link would then be: `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="home_logo_vPK_icon.ico?" type="image/x-icon" />`

Also, did you refresh the cache before testing? If not, reset the cache, or you will not see your changes.

Finally, it could also be your icon. Try using a [favicon generator](http://www.favicon-generator.org/).

Comment: Did you try to add the `?` at the end of the icon name?

Comment: added '?'. waaw, resolved. thank you so much @David G.